# How do I test if my motherboard is failing using Windows 10?

Tags: motherboard

My computer freeze randomly.

I have checked RAM, using new SSD and replace another power supply but problem insisted.

Any way to test my motherboard health is good or not?

Comment: Please edit your question. Your question is way too broad. You need to provide more details. Like what is the exact make and model of the motherboard and PC itself. What about other stuff like RAM, CPU and GPU?

Comment: Check Event Viewer if Windows has registered any event for the reason for freeze, just in case.